# Html Change h1 content on javascript with list

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys I have some mistake I want change h1 content on JavaScript with list but I cant where is my mistake can you help me?

```
<html> 
<body>
    <h2 id="demo">Example H</h2>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"> </div>
</body>
<script> 
next = document.querySelector("swiper-button-next");
name-index = 0;
name-list[
{
 name: 'John'
},
{
name: 'Christina'
}
];
next.addEventListener('click', myFunction)
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML /* (i was try like textContent) */ = "name-list[name-index].name";
}
<script>
<html>
```

Comment: `name-index` is invalid JS variable name, `.innerHTML = "name-list[name-index].name"` will put literal string, not value from _object_ (?!)

Comment: firstly you cannot have hyphen in your variables. secondly specify what is `next` a `var`, `const` or `let` And thirdly `document.querySelector('demo')` what is *demo* here? a class? an id? or something else. Lastly you need to set `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "name-list[name-index].name"` will get treated as a string instead `name-list[name-index].name` remove quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many syntax errors in your HTML/JS.

- you cant use hyphens in variable names
- HTML tags get opened but never closed
- There is content after `</body>`
- use `let`, `const` or `var` for variable declarations
- the query selector was not right: use a "." infront of the CSS class name
- Why is `name_list[name_index].name` in quatation marks? This will only insert the literal as String

```html
 <html>
        <body>
            <h2 id="demo">Example H</h2>
            <div class="swiper-button-next">My Button</div>
            <script> 
              let next = document.querySelector(".swiper-button-next");
              let name_index = 0;
              let name_list = [
                { name: 'John' },
                { name: 'Christina' }
              ];
              next.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
              function myFunction() {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = name_list[name_index].name;
              }
            </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: because i will right now update code;  '''  next.addEventListener('click', NextName);
              function myFunction() {
                siir.innerHTML = name_list[name_index].name;
              }
              function NextName() {
                name_index += 1;
                myFunction();
              } '''

Answer (score 0):

Please check coding format

```html
<html> 
<body>
    <h2 id="demo">Example H</h2>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"> </div>
</body>
<script> 
var next = document.querySelector(".swiper-button-next");
var name_index = 0;
var name_list = [
{
 name: 'John'
},
{
name: 'Christina'
}
];
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML /* (i was try like textContent) */ = name_list[name_index].name;
}
next.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

</script>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it. https://codepen.io/phm-tun-v/pen/wvyRqMe

```
<body>
    <h2 id="demo">Example H</h2>
    <button id="swiper-button-next">Click here</button>
</body>

<script> 
  next = document.getElementById("swiper-button-next");
  let nameIndex = 0;
  let nameList = [{ name: 'John'},{name: 'Christina'}];
  next.addEventListener('click', myFunction)
  function myFunction() {      
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=nameList[nameIndex].name;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much I finally fixed my code

```
<html>            
<body>
...
                <h3 class="poetry-header" id="poetry-h">Sude</h3>
                <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-elements"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-elements"></div>
  <script>
            let prev = document.querySelector(".swiper-button-prev");
            let next = document.querySelector(".swiper-button-next");
            let poetry = document.querySelector("#poetry-h");
              let name_index = 0;
              let name_list = [
                { name: 'Sude' },
                { name: 'Bir Tohumdum Ben' }
              ];
              next.addEventListener('click', NextName);
              function myFunction() {
                poetry.innerHTML = name_list[name_index].name;
              }
              function NextName() {
                name_index += 1;
                myFunction();
              }
              function PrevName() {
               if(name_index >= 1 ) {
                name_index -= 1;
               }
               else{
                name_index = 0;
               }
                myFunction();
              }
              prev.addEventListener('click', PrevName);
         </script>
</body>
</html>
```